# How to include theme from Theme roller on jQ page

Tags: jquery, theming

I wrote some scripts and I would like to "paint" it by using already prepared theme by Theme roller. I like theme **Le Frog** and **UI darkness** but I don't know how to include any of them by direct link, no custom change? I tried some combination but sometime script refuse to work, elements disappeared etc.
Will then it be visible to tablet and PC users too?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try these rows to put into head section:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I think it should work in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I applied it to my page script and it works as I expected. What about mobile devices?